# df.groupby().agg(sum).groupby().mean() does not return the right values as it ignores .agg(sum)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return certain columns that are aggregated together but 2 specific columns where the average across the dates are returned.

```
per_courier = df.groupby(['Rider','Hours','T1 Delivered']).agg(sum).groupby(['Minutes PD', 'Delivery Success']).mean()
```

The output I get right now only returns the `.groupby().mean()` but doesn't seem to aggregate the Rider, Hours and T1 Delivered columns for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.agg()` seemed to work for me if anyone else has this issue. Allows you to apply different functions to specific columns.

```
per_courier = df.groupby('Rider').agg({'Hours': 'sum', 'T1 Delivered':'sum', 'Minutes PD' : 'mean', 'Delivery Success': 'mean'})
```